# What does the acronym or abbreviation in Hatrat Nedarim stand for?

Tags: prayer-book

What do the 4 letters (הויה) stand for or mean? This appears at the beginning of Hatrat Nedarim.

Answer (score 3):

The word הֲוָיָה is not an *acronym or abbreviation*! It's a word, meaning *to bring into being* - as in *Hashem brings the entire world into being*.

In the context of Hatarat Nedarim it refers to the ineffable name of Hashem - YHVH.

> אם נשבעתי בהשם הֲוָיָה ברוך הוא

would, therefore, translate to

> If I swore with the ineffable name of Hashem - YHVH - blessed be He.

We see הֲוָיָה being used in this context in the Tur ([O"C 5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.5.1?lang=bi)):

> ויכוין בברכותיו פירוש המלות שמוציא מפיו
>  ובהזכירו השם יכוין פי' קריאתו באל"ף דל"ת לשון אדנות שהוא אדון הכל
>  ויכוין עוד פירוש כתיבתו ביו"ד ה"א לשון **הֲוָיָה** שהוא היה והוה ויהיה. ...‏
>
> One should concentrate on the meaning of the words when making a blessing.
> When mentioning The Name [of Gcd] he should have in mind the meaning of what he says - i.e. A-d-o-n-a-y - being The Master of the world.
> One should also concentrate on the way the word is written - i.e. Y-H-V-H  - meaning הֲוָיָה - to bring into being, the he always was, is and will be.

Comment: If it is a word, why is it not translated (in the several siddurim I have checked).

Comment: @YehudaW - that's a question for the editors of those Siddurim. :-)

Comment: Which is it?  Does it mean" to bring into being"  or does it "refers to the ineffable name of Hashem - YHVH."